# Simple overloading is black magic to the modern compiler?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

The following code demonstrates the resolution of some templated function overloading,
which appear to be quite trivial in nature. However, it seems that the 3 major compilers—
`Clang`, `GCC`, and `MSVC`—have a different idea about that.

```
namespace t1 { // clang ok, gcc ok, msvc nope
    void operator+(struct s, auto);
    struct s { template<typename...> void operator+(int) const; };
}
namespace t2 { // clang ok, gcc nope, msvc ok
    void operator+(auto, int);
    struct s { template<typename...> void operator+(int) const; };
}
namespace t3 { // clang ok, gcc nope, msvc nope
    void operator+(auto, auto);
    struct s { void operator+(auto) const; };
}
namespace t4 { // clang nope, gcc nope, msvc ok
    void operator+(struct s, auto);
    struct s { void operator+(auto) const; };
}
namespace t5 { // clang nope, gcc ok, msvc nope
    void operator+(auto, int);
    struct s { void operator+(auto) const; };
}
using namespace t1;
static_assert(not noexcept(s{} + int{}));
```

Which compiler is wrong, and which compiler is right in all of these test cases?
And why, exactly? Which specific rules in the standard apply here?
How is the partial ordering of the overload resolution performed exactly?

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/E48qPME8E)

---

##### Error messages

T1 - `MSVC`:

```
<source>(22): error C2593: 'operator +' is ambiguous
<source>(3): note: could be 'void t1::s::operator +<>(int) const'
<source>(2): note: or       'void t1::+<int>(t1::s,_T0)'
        with
        [
            _T0=int
        ]
<source>(22): note: while trying to match the argument list '(t1::s, int)'
<source>(22): error C2056: illegal expression
<source>(22): error C2607: static assertion failed
```

T2 - `GCC`:

```
<source>:22:32: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator+'
    (operand types are 't2::s' and 'int')
   22 | static_assert(not noexcept(s{} + int{}));
      |                            ~~~~^~~~~~~
<source>:7:43: note: candidate: 'void t2::s::operator+(int) const 
    [with <template-parameter-1-1> = {}]'
    7 |     struct s { template<typename...> void operator+(int) const; };
      |                                           ^~~~~~~~
<source>:6:10: note: candidate: 'void t2::operator+(auto:2, int) [with auto:2 = s]'
    6 |     void operator+(auto, int);
      |          ^~~~~~~~
```

T3 - `GCC`:

```
<source>:22:32: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator+'
    (operand types are 't3::s' and 'int')
   22 | static_assert(not noexcept(s{} + int{}));
      |                            ~~~~^~~~~~~
<source>:11:21: note: candidate: 'void t3::s::operator+(auto:5) const
    [with auto:5 = int]'
   11 |     struct s { void operator+(auto) const; };
      |                     ^~~~~~~~
<source>:10:10: note: candidate: 'void t3::operator+(auto:3, auto:4)
    [with auto:3 = s; auto:4 = int]'
   10 |     void operator+(auto, auto);
      |          ^~~~~~~~
```

T3 - `MSVC`:

```
<source>(22): error C2593: 'operator +' is ambiguous
<source>(11): note: could be 'void t3::s::+<int>(_T0) const'
        with
        [
            _T0=int
        ]
<source>(10): note: or       'void t3::+<t3::s,int>(_T0,_T1)'
        with
        [
            _T0=t3::s,
            _T1=int
        ]
<source>(22): note: while trying to match the argument list '(t3::s, int)'
<source>(22): error C2056: illegal expression
<source>(22): error C2607: static assertion failed
```

T4 - `Clang`:

```
<source>:22:32: error: use of overloaded operator '+' is ambiguous
    (with operand types 's' and 'int')
static_assert(not noexcept(s{} + int{}));
                           ~~~ ^ ~~~~~
<source>:14:10: note: candidate function [with auto:1 = int]
    void operator+(struct s, auto);
         ^
<source>:15:21: note: candidate function [with auto:1 = int]
    struct s { void operator+(auto) const; };
                ^
```

T4 - `GCC`:

```
<source>:22:32: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator+'
    (operand types are 't4::s' and 'int')
   22 | static_assert(not noexcept(s{} + int{}));
      |                            ~~~~^~~~~~~
<source>:15:21: note: candidate: 'void t4::s::operator+(auto:7) const
    [with auto:7 = int]'
   15 |     struct s { void operator+(auto) const; };
      |                     ^~~~~~~~
<source>:14:10: note: candidate: 'void t4::operator+(s, auto:6)
    [with auto:6 = int]'
   14 |     void operator+(struct s, auto);
      |          ^~~~~~~~
```

T5 - `Clang`:

```
<source>:22:32: error: use of overloaded operator '+' is ambiguous
    (with operand types 's' and 'int')
static_assert(not noexcept(s{} + int{}));
                           ~~~ ^ ~~~~~
<source>:18:10: note: candidate function [with auto:1 = t5::s]
    void operator+(auto, int);
         ^
<source>:19:21: note: candidate function [with auto:1 = int]
    struct s { void operator+(auto) const; };
                ^
```

T5 - `MSVC`:

```
<source>(22): error C2593: 'operator +' is ambiguous
<source>(19): note: could be 'void t5::s::+<int>(_T0) const'
        with
        [
            _T0=int
        ]
<source>(18): note: or       'void t5::+<t5::s>(_T0,int)'
        with
        [
            _T0=t5::s
        ]
<source>(22): note: while trying to match the argument list '(t5::s, int)'
<source>(22): error C2056: illegal expression
<source>(22): error C2607: static assertion failed
```

Comment: The question isn't bad, but it's asking too many sub-questions at the same time. It would be better to split this up into multiple smaller questions. The reasons why some compilers fail are likely separate conformance issues/bugs, so the answers are also going to be different for each case. At least `t1` and `t2` should be in a question separate from `t3`, `t4`, and `t5`.

Comment: @JanSchultke *"At least `t1` and `t2` should be in separate question..."* But why, though? All of the presented test cases boil down to the same underlying principle, which relates to the partial ordering process of template function overloading. Once that is laid out and analyzed with a certain level of depth and detail, all of these test cases can be explained accordingly. Now, we can argue and disagree about that, but that doesn't make it clear or objective when deciding how to separate these test cases in a certain way. ...

Comment: @JanSchultke ... In fact, the only way to separate these test cases in the most appropriate way possible, is by already having an answer to this question.

Comment: I see one actual question: Which of these examples is correct per the standard?

Comment: @303 So this is an anolog of CRTP for an answer?

Comment: @AlanBaljeu Almost.. those compilers, at least in default mode are notorious to slip through cracks of wording. Even if the code compiled, doesn't mean that  compiler accepted it. GCC is known to sometimes just ignore errors in overloads if it chose another. MSVC doesn't look into templates unless you instantiate it, which leads in accepting ill-formed code

Comment: I think Jan Schultke is right. I think this question should really be 5 separate questions. In each question, you could ask for an explanation of the principles involved. You will not be missing out on the opportunity to learn anything about partial ordering just because the questions are separate.